# Adding Entity Framework to Azure Function: Unable to resolve service for type 'DBContext' while attempting to activate 'Function1'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions

I am trying to add Entity Framework to an Azure Function project (.NET 6.0).

Currently when I run the function I get the error

> "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'FDBContext' while attempting to activate 'Function1'"

Packages:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions v1.1.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational v7.0.5
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v7.0.5
System.Data.SqlClient  v4.8.5
```

Startup.cs

```
class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<FDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer("<Working connection string>");
        });
        builder.Services.AddOptions();
    }
}
```

FDBContext.cs

```
public class FDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public FDBContext(DbContextOptions<FDBContext> context) : base(context)
        {  }
    
        public DbSet<DBData> DBDatas { get; set; }
    }
```

Function1.cs

```
public class Function1
{
        private readonly FDBContext _context;
        public Function1(FDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            var test = _context.DBDatas.ToList();
        }
}
```

Error:

```
[2023-05-15T19:33:34.607Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000008A575D25'.
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.495Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.497Z]   requestId: "53766d70-997b-4fda-a58b-bdae741fd544",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.498Z]   method: "POST",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.499Z]   userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.500Z]   uri: "/api/Function1"
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.501Z] }
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.808Z] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=9181b193-7127-4484-80b3-8ec98d77066e, Duration=39ms)
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.809Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'FiedlDeviceFunctionApp2.FDBContext' while attempting to activate 'FunctionApp2.Function1'.
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.816Z] An unhandled host error has occurred.
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.817Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'FiedlDeviceFunctionApp2.FDBContext' while attempting to activate 'FunctionApp2.Function1'.
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.822Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.823Z]   requestId: "53766d70-997b-4fda-a58b-bdae741fd544",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.823Z]   identities: "(WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin)",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.825Z]   status: "500",
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.826Z]   duration: "325"
[2023-05-15T19:33:44.830Z] }
```

Comment: Can you please post full exception?

Comment: At the end of your configure method, if you do something like `var db = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService(typeof(FDBContext))` does it throw an exception?

Comment: @SamIAm I added "var db = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService(typeof(FDBContext));" , no exception was thrown.

Comment: @user3626232  That probably means that for some reason your function isn't using the Service Provider you configured in startup.  I'd Put a break point there and make sure it's getting hit just to be sure this is the case

Comment: @user3626232 Judging by the nature of the exception, It appears to be using some sort of Service Provider to execute your function.  Just not that one.

Comment: @user3626232 -  Iam able to resolve the issue.Will post the answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Initially even I got the same error, when I have the below tags in `.csproj` file.

```cs
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Startup.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

- Make sure to remove those tags.
- Right click on the `Startup.cs` file,in properties change the `Build action to Content` and `Copy to Output` to `Copy always/Copy if newer` as shown below.

[image]

[image]

I am able to clear the issue by changing the package versions in`.csproj` file.

My `.csproj`  file:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Startup.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `Function1.cs`:***

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using FunctionDBContext.Data;

namespace FunctionDBContext
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly FDBContext _context;
        public Function1(FDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

       
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var test = _context.Items.ToList();
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in query string or in the request body for a response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

***My `FDBContext.cs`:***

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace FunctionDBContext.Data
{
    public class FDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public FDBContext(DbContextOptions<FDBContext> context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<DBData> Items { get; set; }
    }
    [Keyless]
    public class DBData
    {      
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***My `Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
using FunctionDBContext;
using FunctionDBContext.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionDBContext.Startup))]
namespace FunctionDBContext
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<FDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=******\\******;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true");
            });
            builder.Services.AddTransient<FDBContext>();
            builder.Services.AddOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Results from DB:***

[image]

***Function Output:***

[image]

[image]